# Powershell Setting Environment variable for local variable

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, environment-variables

I am getting a list of values from the command line in format of key=val key=val, after splitting them down and then into key and value, I want to set an environment variable using the key.

I have tried the following code ($sstr is being set from arguments, but I have hard coded it to simplify the code), but I am getting 'unexpected token' error:

```
$retrievedVal = "key1=val1 key2=val2"

# Split the string, with space being the delimiter, leaving key=value
$sstr = $retrievedVal .split( " " )

foreach ( $var in $sstr )
{
    $keyvalueList = $var.split( "=" )
    $env:($keyvalueList[0]) = "Test"
}
```

Any suggestions to where I have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Set-Item` cmdlet:

```
$Name,$Value='key1=val1'-split'=',2
Set-Item -LiteralPath Env:$Name -Value $Value
```

Also you could use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` method:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($Name,$Value)
```

Note, what that only set process environment variables. So, it affects only your process and child processes, started from that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Set-Variable` command in PowerShell:

`Set-Variable -Name "..." -Value "..."`

Then you can use a couple of commands to check that the variable was set properly: `echo`, `Write-Host`, `Get-Variable` :

1. `echo $...`
2. `Write-Host "$..."`
3. `Get-Variable -Name "..."`

Example 1:

```
Set-Variable -Name "Employee" -Value "John"

echo $Employee
```

Example 2:

```
Set-Variable -Name "Employee" -Value "John"

Write-Host "$Employee"
```

Example 3:

```
Set-Variable -Name "Employee" -Value "John" 

Get-Variable -Name "Employee"
```